# C++ Execution Script Aprog Command Not Found

Tags: c++, linux, bash, command-line

we have a C++ project in which we need to redirect the standard output to a text file using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Descend into 'workdirectory' directory"
cd workdirectory
#
for item in *
do
echo " "
echo "EXECUTING" $item
cd $item
Aprog >zoutput02.txt
cd ..
echo "EXECUTION COMPLETE"
done
echo "Return from 'testdirectory' directory"
cd ..
echo " "
```

When I try to run this script using bash ./scriptname.txt, it returns:

```
EXECUTING work
./scriptname.txt: line 10: Aprog: command not found
EXECUTION COMPLETE
Return from 'workdirectory' directory
```

What does this error mean?

Thanks!

Comment: Seriously? You can't figure out "Aprog: command not found" ? Your project needs some experience NOW!

Comment: Well, obviously I know what it means.. But how would I fix it? Is that not the correct format to do what I want?

Comment: The short answer for any `command not found` in bash is either **(1)** the command you are attempting to execute is not in your path (check with `set | grep PATH` or **(2)** the execute bit is not set on the file. That will cover almost 100% of the bash command not found scenarios. There are numerous example of setting the Unix path available online.

Answer (score 0):

You are CD ing around.  `Aprog` is almost certainly not on your path.

Either add `Aprog` to your PATH or define it in the script.

```
aprog=/path/to/aprog 
$aprog > zoutput02.txt
```